# Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and error: path not valid for CSV records retriving

Tags: vba, oledb

```vb
currentPath2 = "C:\output-Cities.txt"
    
Dim cn,rs

Set cn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

strConn= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & currentPath2 & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=No'"
cn.ConnectionString = strConn
cn.Open
RS.ActiveConnection = cn
RS.Source = "select * from " & currentPath2
```

It gives error on the `Provider=...`, line says path is not valid, do I need to install OLEDB driver however that is I see OLE folder in my system folder of C drive, please lemme know if I have to achieve anything more. Basically I want to retrieve csv records as in recordsets, please lemme know if anybody can help me here, this has to work in both VBA and LotusScript.

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the reference to your VBA project?

[image: Reference]

Comment: so Do I need to download the drivers for the same ? the problem is with Lotus notes/LotusScript..

Comment: The reference will already be available in your MS application under tools, references. Just add the reference with the most recent version (it may not be 6.1 it could be lower). My knowledge with Lotus is very limited I'm afraid, sorry. Not sure if this is of any use as it ODBC https://www.connectionstrings.com/lotus-notes/